# Why this code is not possible in Kotlin?

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin

Below is a perfectly construct in C++, C# and other similar languages. Why this is not possible in Kotlin

```
open class EndPoint<T> (url: String): T{

...
}

class BlueEndPoint: EndPoint<BlueInterface>{}
class RedEndPoint: EndPoint<RedInterface>{}
```

Answer (score 8):

Because Kotlin uses generics, not templates. It has just one `EndPoint` class instead of creating a new one for every `T` like C++ does.

And on JVM this class needs to extend exactly one superclass (possibly `Object`) and a specific set of interfaces (possibly none). I.e. you can't have `EndPoint<BlueInterface>` implement `BlueInterface` but not `RedInterface` and vice versa for `EndPoint<RedInterface>`.

According to MSDN it doesn't work in C# either (I believe CLR has the same requirement when defining classes):

> [C# does not allow the type parameter to be used as the base class for the generic type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics)

It's C++ which is the exception here.

Comment: Im not using the derived class as the parameter, The generic parameter is a certain class of interfaces. I think you are confusion it with the cute named "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern"

Comment: I think you are the one confusing it: `: T` is exactly what the quoted line disallows, while CRTP works in C#, Java, and Kotlin just fine.

Comment: I've added another paragraph which may make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It caused by the JVM generics restrictions. More information you can read [here] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html).

Comment: Which one of those would that be?